# Editing Dropdown Validation List Event Excel JavaScript - Office_JS

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

I'm trying to see if I can migrate a function I have in VBA for improving Excels horrible Data Validation list UI. Basically, as the user types, I want to search for matches and propose first match, further filtering as they type more.

So far, I've figured out how to detect `DataValidation` lists, get list values, search the list, but when I got to setting up the events, I hit a bit of a wall.

For "Events"

- I tried `onSelectionChanged` but that doesn't work when entering text, just when they click the cell.
- I tried `onChanged` but that only works after the user leaves the cell editing, I'd want it to fire with each keystroke.
- I saw `onDataChanged` and thought that looked promising, but no examples are given how to use this.

I'm starting to think I may have to use a TaskPane or just keep this function w/ VBA, but looking for assistance first!

Update: I'm fairly certain this only worked in VBA because I was able to have events fire inside the Dropdown UI that replaced Excels. I would likely have to use a Dialog or TaskPane window to get the same effect, but if someone wants to answer definitively feel free.